# How to get the first div child with tagname 'a' with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, tampermonkey

JS beginner here.

I'm writing a script to get the comment author of a Facebook comment by pressing a button.

[This image is the HTML i'm working on. It pretty much summarizes what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9LM9.png) (get the name of the comment author)

For now, I'm using

```
var Author = document.elementFromPoint (posX, posY)
var AuthorName = Author.textContent;
```

but it works only when my mouse is exactly on the comment author name. I wanted it to also work when my mouse is on the comment box.

So I wanted to try something like

```
var Comment = document.elementFromPoint (posX, posY);
var Author = Comment.querySelector("a");
var AuthorName = Author.textContent;
```

since the "author" part is the only child of the comment div that is an .

But it's not working.

Author is undefined.

Is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: It would help if you also provided some of the HTML so we can see what you are working with.

Comment: Do you maybe mean "tag name" instead of "attribute"?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, `el.querySelector` won't return `el` even if it matches the query. Consequently, clicking on the 'a' author tag directly will not work with your example.

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them. Use the API.